# Java writes "&#91;" and "&#93;" to a text file instead of "[" and "]"

Tags: java, java-io

I'm taking an input string as Java source code, editing it a little bit, and generate a .java file in Java.

Here is my code.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("javacode.java"));
//msg = msg.substring(4); //ignore this
String newcontent = "import java.io.BufferedWriter;import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;import java.io.FileWriter;import java.io.PrintStream;";
char[] content = msg.toCharArray();
int j = msg.indexOf("String[] args") + 14;
boolean inMain = false;
for (int x=0;x<content.length;x++) {
    if (x == j) {
        inMain = true;
        if (content[j] != '{') {
            j += 1;
            newcontent += String.valueOf(content[x]);
            continue;
        }
        newcontent += String.valueOf(content[x]);
        String prefix = "ByteArrayOutputStream consoleStorage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();PrintStream newConsole = System.out;System.setOut(new PrintStream(consoleStorage));";
        newcontent += prefix;
    }
    else if (content[x] == '}' && inMain) {
        String post = "String str = consoleStorage.toString();try {BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(\"javaoutput.txt\"));writer.write(str);writer.close();} catch (Exception e) {}";
        newcontent += post;
        newcontent += String.valueOf(content[x]);
        inMain = false;
    }
    else {
        newcontent += String.valueOf(content[x]);
    }
}
writer.write(newcontent);
writer.close();
```

It may look a little bit complicated, but generally speaking, I'm adding these three pieces of code into the main method of the source code input.

```
//At the beginning of the program, insert the following code
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
...
...
...
//At the beginning of the main method, insert the following code
ByteArrayOutputStream consoleStorage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream newConsole = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(consoleStorage));
...
...
...
//At the end of the main method, insert the following code
String str = consoleStorage.toString();
try {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("javaoutput.txt"));
    writer.write(str);
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

However, when I test it out, with a simple Hello World example, I got this .java file.

Here is my source code input ("msg" variable, it is a simple String)

```
public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Here is what I got.
(I re-formatted this file for a better look)

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class myClass {

    ByteArrayOutputStream consoleStorage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream newConsole = System.out;
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(consoleStorage));

    public static void main(String&#91;&#93; args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String str = consoleStorage.toString();
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("javaoutput.txt"));
            writer.write(str);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

As you can see, Java fails to put "[" and "]" into the file and write "[]" instead, and thus (probably) "int j = msg.indexOf("String[] args") + 14;" fails to locate the main method.

I tried many methods to fix this, including replacing "[" by "\\[" etc, none of them works. To be honest, I'm not even sure whether "[]" generates the problem.

---

Update:

I tested all contents of "msg" and "content" variable/array in different phases, by inserting the following test prints into my program.

Note:

1. CQ.sendPrivateMsg(msgReceiver, message) is used to send the message to the receiver, this is working appropriately.
2. "msg" variable is passed from the chatting software, which I can only use its API to send/receive messages, while I don't have its source code...

This program is a part of an plugin of a chatting software.

```
...
...
...
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("javacode.java"));
msg = msg.substring(4);

//test print 1
CQ.sendPrivateMsg(fromQQ, CC.at(fromQQ) + "\n" + msg);

String newcontent = "import java.io.BufferedWriter;import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;import java.io.FileWriter;import java.io.PrintStream;";
char[] content = msg.toCharArray();

//test print 2
CQ.sendPrivateMsg(fromQQ, CC.at(fromQQ) + "\n" + content[55] + content[56] + content[57] + content[58]);

//test print 3
String tempstr = new String();
for (int i=0;i<content.length;i++) {
    tempstr += String.valueOf(content[i]);
}
CQ.sendPrivateMsg(fromQQ, CC.at(fromQQ) + "\n" + tempstr);

int j = msg.indexOf("String[] args") + 14;
...
...
...
```

The actual result is shown below

```
//test print 1: msg
public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

//test print 2: char array, accessed each digit one by one
&#91

//test print 3: char array, concatenate in a loop and print out as a whole
public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

It seems like the problem is triggered by the case when I tried to access a single value within the char array, but it is fine when I use a for loop to print it all.

---

Update:

I solved it, by replacing [ and other strange code in char array by [ or ].

Advice given in comment is very helpful. Appreciate!

Comment: Where does `msg` come from? If the chars are already escaped there then we won't find the error in the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your respond! I posted my whole "msg" variable in my question just now.

Comment: "msg" variable is a String, containing all the source code input, shown above

Comment: It looks like the "msg" variable already contains the invalid java code. Use a debugger and go backwards to check where the string come from and what the contents of your variables are.

Comment: Thank you. I will check what "msg" really contains.

Comment: Still don't see where `msg` is declared. But my guese is that a encoding difference might mess up things. Could you provide any information about either of these missing items?

Comment: that thing is handled by the software, which I don't have source code... but I think "msg" is OK, but char array is not. (see update part)

Comment: This is the perfect time to start running through the [mcve] exercise: much of your code is not involved in read or writing files, so start weeding out everything: start with a file that just contains something like `abcd <> [] ,.` to cut out on all your input noise. Does it still happen? Reduce your reader: you're doing tons of content analysis so you can inject more string data: remove all of that and leave that content untouched. Does it still happen? At every step, leave the reduced code and start weeding somewhere else, and in the end you have perfect SO-posting code.

Comment: Check the content of the actual "javacode.java", it looks like it already contains the `& # 9 1 ;` characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like msg is received as an HTML-encoded string.

You may use Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4-java.lang.String-) to decode this string.